# Missing : after property id (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting this error in the firebug console and can't work out why. My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var header = $('h2#chase');
    var headerOffset = header.offset();
    header.css({
        "position" : "absolute",
        "left" : headerOffset.left+"px",
        "top" : headerOffset.top+"px"
    });

    var headerSize = {width: header.width(), height: header.height()};
    var headerBounds = {top: headerOffset.top, right: headerOffset.left + headerSize.width, bottom: headerOffset.top + headerSize.bottom, left: headerOffset.left};
    var windowBounds = {top: 0, right: $(window).width() - headerSize.width, bottom: $(window).height() - headerSize.height, left: 0};
    var maxLeft = $(window).width() - headerSize.width;
    var maxTop = $(window).height() - headerSize.height;

    var margin = 30;

    $(window).mousemove(function(e){
        headerOffset = header.offset();
        headerBounds = {top: headerOffset.top, right: headerOffset.left + headerSize.width, bottom: headerOffset.top + headerSize.height, left: headerOffset.left};
        var sides = whichSides(e.pageX, e.pageY);
        $.each(sides, function(key, value) {
            header.css({
                value.side : value.newValue+"px"
            })
        });
    });

    function whichSides(mouseX, mouseY) {
        var sides = [];
        var sideOffsets = {top: headerBounds.top - mouseY, right: mouseX - headerBounds.right, bottom: mouseY - headerBounds.bottom, left: headerBounds.left - mouseX};
        var newValues = {top: mouseY + margin, right: mouseX - margin, bottom: mouseY - margin, left: mouseX + margin};
        $.each(sideOffsets, function(key, value) {
            if (value < 30 && value >= 0) {
                sides.push({side: key, newValue: newValues[key]});
            }
        });
        return sides;
    }
});
```

The error firebug is returning:

```
    missing : after property id (line 24, col 9)
    value.side : value.newValue+"px"
```

**Edit:** Apologies I seem to of posted the code from a draft I wrote earlier this morning, I have since updated it with the truly erronous code.

Comment: Why do you use `eval` there? Simply `newValues[key]` should return the same result and be much saner code.

Comment: You may want to look at the jquery API for $.each again too.  what you are expecting as key will be the current index and not a css key.

Comment: Also the push syntax is wrong. You should be getting a JS error on page load. change `sides.push{side: key, newValue: eval("newValues."+key)};
` to `sides.push({side: key, newValue: newValues[value]});
`

Comment: I'm not a jquery coder (but trying to get into it)... but should it be `push{`? My non-jquery side says that maybe it should be `push({` (with corresponding `});` at the end.  I've made this a comment, rather than answer because of my lack of experience with it

Comment: @Chandu and freefaller: You should post these as answers, since that is exactly what the question is asking.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I don't know, coming back to javascript after a long hiatus, not used to accessing objects with my index in that form. Much appreciated

Comment: Apologies to people who have noticed errors about syntax I appear to have posted the code from a draft I wrote much earlier today before I found these errors. I have now updated with the real erronous code.

Comment: @George - are you sure firebug is talking about the line starting `sides.push`? Looks more like the line starting `value.side`

Comment: @freefaller you're right, I'm going a bit crazy.

Comment: Use a code validator like http://JSHint.com .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this bit:

```
header.css({
    value.side : value.newValue+"px"
})
```

`value.side` is not a valid construct to be on the left hand side of `:`

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but it should something more on the lines of:

```
header.css({
    side : value.newValue+"px"
})
```

After reading your comment, you could do this:

```
var o = {}

o[value.side] = value.newValue+'px';

header.css(o);
```

Comment: I don't think "side" is something jQuery CSS can handle, either. Do you mean something like `left` or `top`?

Comment: I'm trying to get the value stored in `value.side` to be the property name.

Comment: @ajm `value.side` always equals ether `left` `top` `right` `bottom`

Comment: Like I said "I'm not sure what you're trying to do", just pointing out the syntax error causing the "missing : after property id" error

Comment: Indeed Ben thanks, but I need to somehow replace it with the value store in `value.side`

Answer (score 0):

As Ben pointed out, you can't have variables in the left side (key) of an object literal expression. You will need to set it separately:

```
function make_pair(key, value){
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = value;
    return obj;
}

header.css( make_pair(value.side, value.newValue+"px") )
```